How properly secure main plate inside Crouse-Hinds main panel
Not sure what to call this “plate” bud it’s behind the insulation and the same part that has the hooks the breakers sit in.
It’s very loose. Clearly not secured to the actual box correctly. I see a couple old circlips but that can’t be the only thing intended right?
My expectation is that there should be a nut on these lugs.
Anyone know what the standard is here?




The part you're talking about is called a "backpan" btw, and is generally one of the things that makes up the panel's interior

FYI you need to remove and replace the Bryant BR and Homeline HOM breakers that are in the panel. They don’t belong (not listed as compatible) and may have damaged the bus connections.
